# Define SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate

How to define SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin in ionic, I just installed the plugin using

> ionic plugin add SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

but after running this code :

```
window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check(
          successCallback,
          errorCallback,
          server,
          fingerprint);

     function successCallback(message) {
       console.log(message);
       // Message is always: CONNECTION_SECURE.
       // Now do something with the trusted server.
     }

     function errorCallback(message) {
       console.log(message);
     }
```

this error was showed :

> Cannot read property 'sslCertificateChecker' of undefined

I try to define 'sslCertificateChecker' in angular module like this :

```
var app = angular.module('juruparkir', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'sslCertificateChecker'])
```

but after run, this error was showed :

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   sslCertificateChecker due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'sslCertificateChecker' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I found the answer by myself, after install using

> ionic plugin add SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

don't forget to add :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

in index.html, after that this code should work :

```
window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check(
          successCallback,
          errorCallback,
          server,
          fingerprint);

     function successCallback(message) {
       console.log(message);
       // Message is always: CONNECTION_SECURE.
       // Now do something with the trusted server.
     }

     function errorCallback(message) {
       console.log(message);
     }
```